# file_get_contents and curl doesn't work, blocked tcp port problem

Tags: php, json, firewall, file-get-contents

I'm trying to write a Joomla module which will parse json data from springer api. I have problem with the method "file_get_contents" and other replacements. My problem is that:

> `Warning: file_get_contents(http://www.example.com) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: A socket operation was attempted to an unreachable network. in C:\wamp\www\modules\mod_springer\mod_springer.php on line 72`

After some search, I found out that it may be because of my company's firewall. Is there any way to overcome this problem like changing port I'm using or using another method, or am I stuck here?

Note: allow_url_fopen is enabled. I'm using wamp.

Comment: Are you using proxy to connect to the Internet?

Comment: Did you really use xxx.com like your warning says, or `api.springer.com`? If you used the former, well, chances are that this site is maybe blacklisted by your company^^

Comment: @Gedrox no, im not using proxy

@jurgen no, im using api.springer.com with the key they provide :)

Comment: If you are able to open the address in browser you should be able to connect with PHP as well by passing the same request headers your browser sends.

Comment: @gedrox: irrelevant. The server is a different machine than whatever the browser would be running on. Saying my door is unlocked at home is irrelevant to the status of doors at work.

Comment: The only solution I can think about is to install proxy server on your home computer on port which can be accessed from the work computer and use it to access the resource. It's stupid but the only answer for this except creating exception on the work network.

Answer (score 2):

You're not stuck if you can convince the powers-that-be to allow you access through the firewall to the remote API to which you wish to connect.  As long as you have a legitimate reason and the firewall access can be provisioned in a narrow scope (one specific IP and port), I don't see why you should have a problem getting this access.

Comment: they said they cannot unblock the port 25, but if i have a chance to solve this problem with any other port, they won't be so strict i guess. Do i make file_get_contents work with other ports?

Comment: @Ismail: just put the port into the url: `http://example.com:XXX/...` where XXX is the port number.

Comment: Port 25 shouldn't be used for HTTP requests...that should be for SMTP.  Are you sure you have that right?

Comment: @Ismail AJ is 100% right, HTTP requests will normally be over port 80 or as an alternative 8080. Why are you trying to use port 25 anyway?

Comment: @Marc 

`$arr = json_decode(file_get_contents($json_feed_url),true);
var_dump($arr);`

this doesn't work, either.

Comment: @Ismail: As AJ said... port 25 is not something you can file_get_contents on via an HTTP url. port 25 is for SMTP (email). Until YOUR code sends something, the remote server will not send anything back, and your error messsage in the original question indicates that port 25 is firewalled off (therefore unreachable).

Comment: @Marc I know port 25 is for SMTP as i said below. Is my approach wrong or is there problem in code, can you clarify please? i tried port 80 both in file_get_contents and curl.

Answer (score 1):

It may be possible (MAYBE) to overcome the issue with cURLs proxy handling like:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, 8080);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD, "xxx:xxx");
```

This would depend on a few things like the permissions you have, if it is just a blocked port or if it is access control.

Comment: Thanks for your effort but still doesnt work, response is "false".

Comment: i was not using port 25 directly, in fact i didn't point any port in the code. IT guys said i can use 80 or 8080. Below the code is still not working. Any suggestions?

`$json_feed_url ='http://api.springer.com:80/metadata/json?q=avionics&api_key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $json_feed_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, 80);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD, "xxx:xxx"); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$json = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$arr = json_decode($json);
var_dump($arr);`

Comment: Have you tried removing the port specification from the URL string in $json_feed_url? You may also want to try using the 0 and 1 values for curl instead of true and false, I am not 100% sure why but I have found at times this has worked for me

Comment: So what ports are available to you?

Answer (score 1):

1. Download `cacert.pem` file from [here](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html)
2. Copy `cacert.pem` file to for example `c:/wamp/bin/php/extras/ssl` folder
3. Write or uncomment in `php.pni` `curl.cainfo ="c:/wamp/bin/php/extras/ssl/cacert.pem" and save`
4. Restart Wamp/Xampp server
5. DONE